# Como sumar el peso en megas de una carpeta de archivos.zip en un HOSTING

Tags: php

Tengo que poner un limite en una carpeta para subir archivos tengo este script:

```
                $tam1 = filesize(glob('*.patch',GLOB_BRACE));{
                echo 'Total de peso = '.$tam1.' MBs<br/>';

                if ($tam1>=512MBs){
                die ('Peso maximo alcanzado por favor disminuya su peso ya no                                                                                                   es permitido seguir subiendo files');
                    }else{die ('Éxito al subir files');}
```

De la carpeta que contiene X cantidad de Archivos sin subcarpetas  SOLO ARCHIVOS:

**html_public/files/*.zip**

Necesito 2 cosas

1. Que imprima el valor pero que sea según el paso 2
2. Pasar su peso a megas para un mejor control Tomando en cuenta que hay archivos que pesan menos de 1 mega. con 2 decimales si son tan amables de indicarme ¿Qué me hace falta? Gracias

Comment: Hay varias maneras de resolver esto; las mas eficientes requieren mayores detalles de contexto como sistema operativo, sistema de archivos, ¿subdirectorios?, frecuencia de uso. Si se trata de un trabajo escolar, prototipo o prueba de concepto, la solución puede ser mas simple.

Comment: Edición hecha amigo se entiende mejor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En binario, un kilobyte son 1024 bytes, y un megabyte son 1024 kilobytes.
Por lo tanto:

```
$bytes = array_sum(array_map('filesize',glob('html_public/files/*.zip')));
$megas = round($bytes/(1024*1024),2);
```

El resultado de `glob` es un arreglo, que lo podemos pasar a `array_map` para aplicarle la función `filesize` a cada elemento.

La abreviatura de la unidad resultante es *MiB*, en cambio, si lo divides por `1000*1000` la unidad es *MB*; es muy común el uso incorrecto de la abreviatura.